# Finding Memoryleaks In Data Structures

Tags: javascript

Looking for constructive criticism on my code below for detecting a memory leak in a data structure.

```
    MemoryLeak = {

  uniq_id: (new Date()).getTime(),
  checked: 1,
  is_seen: [],

  checkLeaks: function(obj) {
    var self = MemoryLeak

    if(!obj || (typeof obj == 'function') || self.checked > 20000)
      return;

    if ((self._isArray(obj) || self._isObject(obj))) {
      if (self._isArray(obj)) {
        self._logTooBig(obj, obj.length)
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
          self._checkIfNeeded(obj[i])
        }
      }
      else if (self._isObject(obj)) {
        self._logTooBig(obj, self._keys(obj).length)

        for (var key in obj) {
          self._checkIfNeeded(obj[key])
        }
      }
    }
  };

  _checkIfNeeded: function(obj) {
    if (!obj)
      return;

    var self = MemoryLeak;
    self.checked++

    if ((self._isArray(obj) || self._isObject(obj))) {
      if(obj.__leaks_checked == self.uniq_id)
        return;
      obj.__leaks_checked = self.uniq_id

      setTimeout(self._partial(self.checkLeaks, obj), 5);
    }
  };

  _logTooBig: function(obj, limit) {
    if (limit > 200) {
      console.log('Object too big, memory leak? [size: ' + limit + ']')
      console.log(obj)
      console.log('-------')
    }
  };

  _keys: function(obj) {
    var rval = [], prop
    for (prop in obj)
      rval.push(prop)
    return rval;
  };

  _isArray: function(obj) {
    try {
      return obj instanceof Array
    }
    catch(e) {
      return false;
    }
  };

  _isObject: function(obj) {
    return (typeof obj == 'object')
  };

  _partial: function(fn) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
    args.shift()
    return function() {
      var new_args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
      args = args.concat(new_args)
      return fn.apply(window, args)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a little confused here

> ```
> if ((self._isArray(obj) || self._isObject(obj))) {
>   if (self._isArray(obj)) {
>     self._logTooBig(obj, obj.length)
>     for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
>       self._checkIfNeeded(obj[i])
>     }
>   }
>   else if (self._isObject(obj)) {
>     self._logTooBig(obj, self._keys(obj).length)
>
>     for (var key in obj) {
>       self._checkIfNeeded(obj[key])
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

because it looks like you are asking the same two questions twice.

why not get rid of the outside if statement and simply make it

```
  if (self._isArray(obj)) {
    self._logTooBig(obj, obj.length)
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
      self._checkIfNeeded(obj[i])
    }
  }
  else if (self._isObject(obj)) {
    self._logTooBig(obj, self._keys(obj).length)

    for (var key in obj) {
      self._checkIfNeeded(obj[key])
    }
  }
```

it is the exact same thing

Answer (score 2):

```
_logTooBig: function(obj, limit) {
  if (limit > 200) {
    console.log('Object too big, memory leak? [size: ' + limit + ']')
    console.log(obj)
```

Naming: Surely the parameter you've called `limit` ought to be named `size`! The word "limit" implies an upper bound, as in "speed limit". In this case, the "limit" on object size is `200`. The parameter you've currently *called* `limit` is the thing you're supposed to be *comparing to* the size limit. What it actually represents is just a *size*.

Separately, are you at all worried that repeatedly `console.log`ging (only) huge objects will be a bad debugging experience? Or do good browsers already handle huge objects just fine?

---

```
var self = MemoryLeak;
self.checked++
```

Syntax nit: missing semicolon after `++`. This is legal of course, but I think many linters will flag it as an inconsistency.

Why do you do this thing with `self = MemoryLeak` instead of just saying `this.checked++`? I might be exposing my own lack of knowledge here, but I thought `this` was supposed to do the right thing in "member" functions called with the `MemoryLeak.foo()` syntax. Is your use of `self` actually working around a problem with `this`, or is it just an idiosyncrasy that could be cleaned up?

---

```
try {
  return obj instanceof Array
}
catch(e) {
  return false;
}
```

Again I may be exposing my own lack of knowledge, but I'm about 75% sure that `instanceof` cannot possibly throw an exception. What case are you worried about here?

---

```
  _keys: function(obj) {
    var rval = [], prop
    for (prop in obj)
      rval.push(prop)
    return rval;
  };
```

This should at least be rewritten

```
  _keys: function(obj) {
    var rval = [];
    for (var prop in obj)
      rval.push(prop);
    return rval;
  };
```

and (unless I'm missing something) it should simply be

```
  _keys: function(obj) { return Object.keys(obj); }
```

---

```
if(!obj || (typeof obj == 'function') || self.checked > 20000)
  return;
```

I see where you initialize `checked = 1` and where you `checked++`, but I don't see anywhere that `checked`'s value decreases or is reset. So do you only ever check 20000 entities and then stop checking forever? That doesn't seem like super useful behavior, since memory leaks typically manifest only after a fairly long time. What's the point of the `checked` counter? (If you keep it, then it would be a good idea to add a `//code comment` explaining why it's desirable. Code comments are great for explaining the "why" of code.)

Speaking of "explain the why": it would have been nice to see an example of how you expect the user to *use* this leak checker. I gather that he'd just insert a call to `MemoryLeak.checkLeaks(mySuspiciousObject)` after initializing the object, and that would trigger the checking of `mySuspiciousObject` every 5 seconds for 20000 iterations?

---

Certainly exposing my ignorance: I wasn't aware that all your `};`s were legal. I thought you'd have to make them `},`.